# RelativeLayout alignParentBottom conflict with android_weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to design my interface using the weight attribute in order to get a nice view on different screen sizes.
Basically, I use a vertical LinearLayout containing 3 RelativeLayouts (header, content and footer). I would like the header and the footer to be 15% each and the content 70% of the height. However, when I set a widget in the header for example, with alignParentBottom="true", everything messes up. It is the same problem if I use a widget with a height="fill_parent", the header fills all the LinearLayout!

[Edit] : I use the NoActionBar theme and that seems to be related to my problem as if I change to the default theme, it fixes the problem. However, I really need to hide the ActionBar...

**What I have:**
[image: layout messes up]

**What I would like to do:**
[image: layout OK]

The problem is that for example, I would like to position the date at the bottom of header...

**Here's a simplify code for the header:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fond_header"
    android:layout_weight=".2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateForm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fond_date_header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here's the footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fond_header"
    android:layout_weight=".2" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/retourBouton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
        android:src="@drawable/retour" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and here's a simplified code of the full interface:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks by advance,

Valentin

Comment: Must be code that is not posted yet. When I use the code you've posted so far, it shows up as you want it to.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to post the footer code...

Comment: Basically, I have noticed, that everything I write inside the footer messes up the interface.. :/ But it remains because of the alignParentBottom in the header as if I remove it, everything goes well... It's the same problem with alignParentTop on a widget in the footer

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to read when the weights are in the same layout file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <include layout="@layout/header"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight=".2"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".6" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/footer"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight=".2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your header and footer I removed the layout_weight, and set height/width to match_parent. The main layout will override those.

Update: Added header + footer.

Header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateForm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/retourBouton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:contentDescription=""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to show the modifications to the header and footer I had to make because I did not have the resources you referenced. Maybe it has to do with the android:background="@drawable/fond_header"?

Comment: Oh I understand the difference, it's because I use the theme NoActionBar, if I change to the default Theme, it fixes the problem. However, I really need to use the NoActionBar theme... :/

Comment: Which NoActionBar theme? android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar?

Comment: I just try and seems to be a bug only in the graphical view in eclipse but when i try it in the emulator, everything's fine :D

Comment: Ok, I was using Android Studio for this.